# CSS / iPod touch: Font becomes much bigger if I add another line of text

Tags: iphone, css

I have a webpage that I am now making work on an ipod touch. The webpage container is 480 pixels wide (450+30 padding) and then it has two divs, each with a single line of text.

When I have just one div of text, then the text appears on a single line, just like on my computer. However, when I add the second div, the iPod touch decides to make the text much bigger (for both divs), such that the text goes onto the next line.

How do I ensure that the text remains the same (smaller) size, no matter how many divs I add? I would like it to the same as on my computer. The user must be able to zoom.

css:

```
body{
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    margin:0px;
 }

.container{
    padding:15px 15px 1px 15px;
    width:450px;
    background:white;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.quote{
    padding-bottom:3px; 
    font-style:italic; 
    text-align:center; 
    width:450px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
  }
```

html:

```
<meta id="meta" name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />

<body >
    <div class= "container">
        <div class = "quote">"I want to be on one line and so does the other line. Even if two."</div>
        <div class = "quote">"I want to be on one line and so does the other line. Even if two."</div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to class container and now it works. Is there any reason NOT to do this? I didn't add it to body because I don't really know what other affects it might have.

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```